# Cakephp - Custom authentification (basicauth) in a plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins, basic-authentication, restful-authentication

I am currently developing an Restfull API for my website. 
I decided to develop it as a plugin.

I am using a custom class that extends `BasicAuthentification`. It allows me to check the client-app credential, in order to limit the API use to only approved developers.

This file works perfectly when added in the CakePHP CORE : `Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/DeviceAuthentification.php`

Since I am developing a Plugin, I would like everything to be inside the same directory.
Therefore in my plugin directory called `MyApi`, I added my custom class in the following path :

`MyApi/Controller/Auth/DeviceAuthentification.php`

In order to load it, in my Plugin's controller `MyApiAppController`, I added the following code :

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => 'Device', // I also tried MyApi.Device
        'sessionKey' => false
    )

);
```

It does not load, the error is the following :

> Authentication adapter "Device" was not found.

Anybody has an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, after having a look in the core file AuthComponent, it seems that you need to have the following path :

MyApi/Controller/**Component**/Auth/DeviceAuthentification.php

instead of

MyApi/Controller/Auth/DeviceAuthentification.php

Therefore, whenever you are working in the **Plugin directory**, you need to add the directory **Component**